# How to combining multiple dependencies into a maven artifact?

Tags: maven, gradle

I have a dependency in a project of mine that does not declare its own required dependencies. How may I combine the dep and its deps into a single maven artifact, so that I can depend on this single artifact instead?

The first (and maybe? second) implementation dependency is the actual public API.

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'http://devsite.ctr-electronics.com/maven/release/'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "com.ctre.phoenix:api-java:5.14.1"
    implementation "com.ctre.phoenix:wpiapi-java:5.14.1"
    implementation "com.ctre.phoenix:cci:5.14.1"
    implementation "com.ctre.phoenix:canutils:5.14.1"
    implementation "com.ctre.phoenix:platform-stub:5.14.1"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `java-library` plugin (emphasis mine):

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html

> The `api` configuration should be used to declare dependencies which are **exported by the library API**, whereas the `implementation` configuration should be used to declare dependencies which are internal to the component.

So change `implementation` to `api` for the dependencies you want exposed on the classpath.